# How to run 2 firebase cloud functions at a time

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-functions

I want to run 2 firebase cloud functions at a time I have tried some method but it is throwing an error when functions are triggered. I have 2 childs in the database and when any changes occur in the childs it should show a notification to users. can anyone help me out of this.

This is database image showing 2 childs in database:

[image: click to see the image]

this is my `index.js` file

```js
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

const fooModule = require('./foo');
const barModule = require('./bar');

exports.foo = functions.database.ref('app_title').onWrite(fooModule.handler);
exports.bar = functions.database.ref('db_kinda/{Uid}/comment').onWrite(barModule.handler);
```

this is my `foo.js` file

```js
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

// Listens for new debate topic created
exports.appTitle = (event) => {
    console.log('Push notification event triggered');

       const app_title = change.after.val();

        if (!change.after.exists() && change.before.exists()) {
            return change.before.val();         
        }

        const payload = {notification: {
            title: 'New Notification',
            body: `${app_title}`
        }};

   return admin.messaging().sendToTopic("appGlobal",payload)
       .then(function(response){
            console.log('Notification sent successfully:',response);
       })
       .catch(function(error){
            console.log('Notification sent failed:',error);
       });
};
```

this is my `bar.js` file

```js
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

exports.data = (event) => {
    console.log('Push notification event triggered');

       const comment = change.after.val();

        if (!change.after.exists() && change.before.exists()) {
            return change.before.val();         
        }

        const payload = {notification: {
            title: 'New Notification',
            body: `${comment}`
        }};

   return admin.messaging().sendToTopic("appGlobal",payload)
       .then(function(response){
            console.log('Notification sent successfully:',response);
       })
       .catch(function(error){
            console.log('Notification sent failed:',error);
       });
};
```

This functions are deploying properly but when it runs on firebase functions it throws error like this

> TypeError: handler is not a function
>       at cloudFunction (/srv/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:127:23)
>       at /worker/worker.js:825:24
>       at 
>       at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:229:7)

Answer (score 0):

As the error says, `handler` is not a function. When you import `foo` for example, you're getting the value of `exports` which has a property called `appTitle`, not `handler`. Try this:

```js
const fooModule = require('./foo');
exports.foo = functions.database.ref('app_title').onWrite(fooModule.appTitle);
```

Or, change your `./foo` export to:

```js
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

// Listens for new debate topic created
exports.handler = (event) => {
  ...
};
```

Comment: Thank you your solution is working now. @I'm Joe Too